# Use an app's model's object fields as form ChoiceField in another app

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have two apps,`menu` and `table`

This is a model in app `menu`

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Item Name", max_length=200, db_index=True)
```

And in app `table`, I have a `form.py` as following:

```
from django import forms

class TableForm(forms.Form):
    item = forms.ChoiceField(choices= xxx)
```

I would like to use the list of all object names in the model `Item` as a `choicelist` in the form. The objects of `Item` could be created both by `admin` and elsewhere in my project during runtime and updated in the database. Could someone advise? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to use a [**`ModelChoiceField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField). If you override the `__str__(…)` method, the method that tells how the textual representation of an object looks like, we can work with a

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='Item Name',
        max_length=200,
        db_index=True
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Then the form looks like:

```
from django import forms
from menu.models import Item

class TableForm(forms.Form):
    item = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Item.objects.all())
```

It might be a good idea to make the `name` of an `Item` unique, such that no two `Item`s are given the *same* name, this could result in confusion, since if two items are named *Apple*, then the question is "*What is the right apple?*":

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='Item Name',
        max_length=200,
        db_index=True,
        unique=True  # ← mark the name as unique
    )

    # …
```